# Is Angular Flex Layout a good choice for future developments

Tags: css, angular, frontend, angular-flex-layout

Is Angular Flex Layout a good choice for future developments?. it is already deprecated. but I saw many weekly downloads in npmjs.com

I'm going to start new angular project with angular 15 version. so, I need an idea about that to use Flex Layout in my project. can you help me

Comment: If you start new project go Angular 16. Also I would advise against it, since they will stop support at some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you notice that a library is deprecated, do not start using it, because you will have additional effort in the future to migrate away from it. But always check the deprecation message in the library, usually they recommend what you should use instead.

In this case [Angular flexlayout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) links to [this Angular blog post](https://blog.angular.io/modern-css-in-angular-layouts-4a259dca9127) which recommends to use CSS flexbox.

Some hints for that:

When I use CSS flexbox, I love this overview: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And if you are not familiar with the syntax, you can practice it with flexbox froggy: https://flexboxfroggy.com/